# Is "A list which its items are..." wrong?

Tags: which-that

I'm writing a piece of documentation for a program, I want to specify the return value of a function.
For sake of simplicity, I've assumed here that the function always returns a list with two items inside (i.e. [1, 2]).
For the "Return" part of the documentation, I need a sentence which indicates that

1. The return type is "list"
2. Items of the list are 1 and 2

What I wrote was

> Return: A list which its items are 1 and 2

But one of my colleagues believes that

> Return: A list the items of which are 1 and 2

is a better representation.

I want to know that:

1. Is the first sentence wrong?
2. Is the second form preferred?

Comment: Please provide a reasonable amount of context.

Comment: @HotLicks I've added some context, hope it's enough

Comment: The possessive of *which* is *whose*. Please use a dictionary. There is no such thing as "which its". The word for that is "whose".

Answer (score 1):

The first expression has incorrect syntax. I would say: “a list, whose items are 1 and 2...”

Comment: I agree.  The use of "whose" does not imply that this list is a person.

Comment: Yes GEdgar - yet another oddity of the English language!